# Unity 5 Control via wasd with rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to implement a simple controlling for my camera in Unity. Successfully I react on pressed w, a, s, d and move the camera. I also want to implement a rotation (Later on rotation with mouse, but at first a rotation using the keys e and q). I've written this script to update my camera but the problem: If you turn around, the update process for my keys w, a, s and d are not working correctly. F.e. I want to go left, but I'll go right. I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can someone give me an idea? 
Here is my source code. Hope you'll understand what's my problem.

```
        float translation_v = -(Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")) * 4.0F * Time.deltaTime;
    camera.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 0, translation_v);
    float translation_h = -(Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")) * 4.0F * Time.deltaTime;
    camera.transform.position += new Vector3 (translation_h, 0, 0);
    float rotation = -(Input.GetAxis ("Rotate_Player")) * 4.0F * Time.deltaTime * 10F;
    camera.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0F, rotation, 0F));
    Vector3 pos = camera.transform.position;
    pos.y = terrain.GetComponent<Terrain>().SampleHeight(camera.transform.position)+1;
    camera.transform.position = pos;
```

Comment: This is how to accept answers on SO http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png Try it on two of your other questions. I guarantee you that it works. When you are done doing this, reply to me and I show you why your code is not working. Otherwise, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Unity has standard components for first person controller and you don't have to do it from scratch, check out Assets -> Import Package -> Characters.

Assuming you do it for educational purposes and just want to implement it yourself: as far as I understood you want to move in the direction of the camera. So, what you need is to multiply the value you add to `camera.transform.position` by current camera rotation, i.e instead of

```
camera.transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 0, translation_v);
```

use

```
camera.transform.position += (camera.transform.rotation * new Vector3 (0, 0, translation_v));
```

and same for horizontal. You may also consider moving rotation update before position update. The final code would look like this:

```
float rotation = -(Input.GetAxis ("Rotate_Player")) * 4.0F * Time.deltaTime * 10F;
camera.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0F, rotation, 0F));

float translation_v = -(Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")) * 4.0F * Time.deltaTime;
camera.transform.position += (camera.transform.rotation * new Vector3 (0, 0, translation_v));
float translation_h = -(Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")) * 4.0F * Time.deltaTime;
camera.transform.position += (camera.transform.rotation * new Vector3 (translation_h, 0, 0));

Vector3 pos = camera.transform.position;
pos.y = terrain.GetComponent<Terrain>().SampleHeight(camera.transform.position)+1;
camera.transform.position = pos;
```